# Shorter alias for domain name

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, percona

I need to create a shorter name for my Mysql database endpoint to be accessed from linux box.
Clearly said, my mysql end point is rdsbench.c2wfqsdsqd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com and I would like to create a shorter name, let's say mybenchdb, so I could use:

```
mysql -hmybenchdb
```

instead of:

```
mysql -hrdsbench.c2wfqsdsqd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com.
```

**EDIT:**
actually I'm using percona toolkit to benchmark rds and compare it to mysql hosted on ec2. The command line is as follows:

```
pt-upgrade mysql-slow.log.1 h=host1 h=rdsbench.c2wffzqsdsqs.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

so what I would like to do is shorten the rds endpoint I'm passing as parameter for this command.

Comment: Why not just use the IP address?

Comment: @JohnGardeniers AWS RDSes can change IPs, without warning.

Comment: I'm trying to do the sam thing and I can't find a way, did you find something? Sorry for not comenting, I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem:

1. Get the public IP address of RDS endpoint

   ```
   $ nslookup rdsbench.c2dddddddx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
   Address: 10.271.12.X
   ```
2. Add this IP address along with your favourite alias name to `/etc/hosts` file

   ```
   10.271.12.X  mybenchdb
   ```

Comment: AWS RDSes can change IPs, without warning.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a local DNS server to resolve it to a shorter name. If you are connecting from a bash shell, you could also do,

```
$ export mybenchdb="rdsbench.c2wfqsdsqd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
$ mysql -h$mybenchdb
```

Add the export to .profile or .bash_profile and it should be permanent.

Comment: It should work with this:
`export mybenchdb="rdsbench.c2wfqsdsqd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"`
`pt-upgrade mysql-slow.log.1 h=host1 h=$mybenchdb`

Comment: that's exactly what I did, but the problem is that the mysql endpoint is showing in pt-upgrade results

Comment: Adding an entry to the hosts file or setting a search base in the hosts.conf is probably more sensible than trying to modify the DNS server - you'll break other stuff if you claim to have authoritative records for a domain you don't really control.

Comment: @symcbean Except on AWS RDS, the IP of your RDS can change on its own.